# Display issue of "minutes" and "mins" in the bounty notices

Tags: feature-request, bounties, timestamps

In the bounty notice, in some places the count down timer is showing as "**x minutes**" whereas in other places it is showing as "**x mins**".

Can it be consistent in both places?

Bounty notice when it is going to end shortly:

> [image: Bounty notice when it is going to end shortly]

Bounty notice when it is in grace period:

> [image: Bounty notice when in grace period]